# How to share text with image in facebook feed using react-native-share?

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-share, react-native-share

I want to share an image with some predefined text on Facebook. To share the image I am using react-native-share. I am able to share the image but the text fields always come as empty. I am sharing the code I am using below. If someone knows a way to share text with the image then please help me.

```
const shareOptions = {
              title: 'Title Here',
              message: `Text I want to share,
              caption: 'Tried adding the caption here didn't work',
              social: Share.Social.FACEBOOK,
              urls: [facebookImage],
            };
            Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
```

Comment: Had you got solution @prince ?